# windows powershell displaying processes in taskbar and output file to csv file

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I am searching for windows powershell command for displaying processes in taskbar and output file to csv file.

I need all data in a tabular form like CPU Memory data network and GPU. And need output of same to be available in a text or CSV format.

Comment: Anyone can help me on this? or please suggest any other forum for a quicker response

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
PS C:\Documents and Settings > Get-Process -IncludeUserName YOURDOMAIN\YOURUSERNAME | 
where {$_.mainWindowTitle} | 
Select-Object -Property ProcessName, TotalProcessorTime, VirtualMemorySize, WorkingSet, MainWindowTitle, Responding, UserName 
| Export-Csv  -Path .\Output.csv
```

`IncludeUserName YOURDOMAIN\YOURUSERNAME` will filter processes running with the credentials of the user logged in.

`| where {$_.mainWindowTitle}` will further filter to show the processes with a GUI.

Or maybe only one of these, to match your needs.
***Edit***: splitting into many lines to avoid the scroll bar.

Comment: Well done. Had to delete my sorry response. The 'IncludeUserName' parameter requires elevated user rights. Delete that part, and it runs in regular session.

Comment: I am unable to run the command , getting below mentioned error.

Get-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'and'.
At line:1 char:1
+ PS C:\Documents and Settings > Get-Process -IncludeUserName ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand